# Fill and SUBMIT web form through .NET Windows Application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, windows, autofill

I need help with one of my requirement (may be weird though, but it is how it should be). I am developing a WINDOWS/DESKTOP .NET APPLICATION utility. This utility will accept the UID,PWD, SERVER and DB and will open:

1. SSMS
2. New instance of default browser, load the any pre-defined web page (this page will have fields for UID,PWD, SERVER and DB), and will AUTO-SUBMIT this request to the server.

This will server two purposes of opening the SSMS and logging in to web application without user interventions.

I would like to know through WINDOWS/DESKTOP .NET APPLICATION, "How can I open the web browser (IE/Chrome etc.), load the pre-defined web page and fill and submit the login credentials to the server?". All this on single button click of my WINDOWS/DESKTOP .NET APPLICATION utility.

Any kind of help would be really really helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you do any research?

Comment: IE ,chrome takes command line arguments where you can pass the URL to open web pages you want...

Comment: Better yet  use WebBrowser control and you can easily update form and submit it.

Comment: @viru WebBrowser control will open the web page in the windows application. I want to open the web page in the real browsers like IE. chrome

Comment: Even if you open thru IE instance, it will open website

Comment: I want to implement functionality like ROBOFORM

Comment: @Viru Right but it wont auto fill the fields and submit the login request

Comment: In webbrowser you can easily auto fill fields and submit the form...Only down side is your win form will show that web browser control.....on the other hand, if you want to open seperate browser and submit the form...Opening website in browser as I mentioned can be done easily by passing URL as command line argument to IE,chrome exe but to run script which will automatically fill the data will require you to build browser add on...without which it is not possible to do so.....

Comment: do some research on selenium tool....it is used for automatic tests...so it should have way to fill the form and submit automaticaly....then you can have C# code which opens browser with url and then it triggers the selenium tool with scirpt which will auto fill data and submit form

Comment: ok. Thanks. I will try it out